# Does it make sense to throw an exception which is always chained?

Tags: java, exception

I'm working on a message library and the send method of an object can fail for a number of reasons such as the socket being closed, etc.

I favor checked exceptions over runtime exceptions but I'm wondering if it would then be more appropriate to favor chaining the exceptions early such that the underlying exception is always wrapped in another, more generalized exception.

For example, a message may only throw a checked `SendFailedException` but the `cause()` would be more specific such as `SocketClosedException`. This feels like it would be less cluttered than having all of the checked exceptions being thrown individually.

Inheritance doesn't quite work here as a `SocketClosedException` can be thrown for other methods as well. And not every closed exception is a result of a failure to send.

Would it be appropriate to wrap further information in `cause()` or would this end up being more confusing? I don't recall finding exceptions functioning in this way in the wild and this might be unconventional and confusing for others.

Does Java or other libraries ever do this? Is it appropriate for my use case?

Comment: Almost every library with sane checked (or unchecked) exceptions defines their own exception hierarchy via inheritance. And whenever there is an exception that needs to be rethrown it should be used as cause, cause that is what it's for.

Comment: `And not every closed exception is a result of a failure to send.` can you give an example what closed exception is not a failure to send?

Comment: A closed exception might be thrown while attempting to query invalid state from a socket after its been closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would it be appropriate to wrap further information in cause() or
>   would this end up being more confusing ?

You can always use `cause` to wrap the original exception which will provide more details about the root/origin of the exception in the stacktrace. You can refer Exception API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29) which explains how cause can be set to wrap exceptions.

> Does Java or other libraries ever do this? Is it appropriate for my
>   use case ?

In many libraries, this pattern is followed, just to pin point, in spring-mvc, `NestedServletException` will be thrown by the container which will wrap the original exception with the cause. Yes, in your case, you can throw `SendFailedException` by setting the cause as `SocketClosedException`.

Also, if your **message library** is from third party, ensure that the 3rd party `Exception` classes don't spread across your project/classes, rather wrap/convert them into your own `Exception` classes so that your code is not tightly coupled with 3rd party `Exception` classes (even if you have to migrate from it).